# Pythonic way to remove DRY in a class that allows a dependency to be injected

Tags: python

How to remove DRY or to make it more Pythonic in a code like this? I know I can make the insertion as a function but I don't like that, many classes will have too many functions because code like these with different implementations are everywhere.

The injected db_conn is managed by Nameko's (microservice framework) DependencyProvider, the closing of the connection is done by the DepedencyProvider when a worker already finished the job.

I also made the db_conn object compatible with `with` statement. I close the connection in the `__exit__` method.

Here is the current code.

```
class CommandChatBot(BaseChatBot):

    def __init__(self, db_conn=None):
         self.db_conn = None
         if db_conn:
             self.db_conn = db_conn

    def add_interaction(self, question, answer, recipient):

        if self.db_conn:
            self.db_conn.use_or_create_db(db=recipient)
            return self.db_conn.insert(
                table=schemas.commandchatbot.TABLE,
                document={
                    'question': question,
                    'answer': answer
                }
            )
        else:
            with db_connection_factory() as conn:
                conn.use_or_create_db(db=recipient)
                return conn.insert(
                    table=schemas.commandchatbot.TABLE,
                    document={
                       'question': question,
                       'answer': answer
                    }
                )
```

The code above is also inefficient when a dependency is not injected, because each functions must instantiate their own db_conn object. I'm thinking about something like a `with` statement but for the whole class, is that possible?

Here's the closing of the connection when a dependency is a subclass of DependencyProvider, get_depedency() is called when a microservice dispatch a new worker, worker_teardown() will be called on worker deletion/all code inside a microservice is already executed.

```
class DbConnectionProvider(DependencyProvider):

        def __init__(self):
            self.db_conn = db_connection_factory()

        def get_dependency(self, worker_ctx):
            return self.db_conn

        def worker_teardown(self, worker_ctx):
            self.db_conn.close_conn()
```

One of the object generated by the db_conn_factory()

```
class RethinkDbAdapter(DatabaseAdapter):

    def __init__(self, db=None, create_db_if_not_exist=True):
        uri = build_nosqldatabase_uri(return_dict=True)

        self.raw_connection = r.connect(
            host=uri['host'],
            port=uri['port']
        )

        ...........

    # __enter__ and __exit__ allows the use of 'with' statement
    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    # Close connection when 'with' statement is out of scope
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.raw_connection.close()

    def close_conn(self):
        """
        Only used in Nameko DependencyProvider.
        """
        return self.raw_connection.close()

    .........
```

Comment: It's not clear to me from your code what you want to happen when.  When do you want the db connection object to be created, and when do you want it to be destroyed/discarded/closed/whatever?

Comment: db_conn object is created when a microservice dispatch a new worker, this db_conn object will be used by many classes inside the worker to interact with the database, I inject the db_conn into those classes. When the worker finished the task, the db_conn automatically close the connection (because it follows the implementation of DepedencyProvider). But, when I want just to test my classes (not the microservice) without going through the microservice, I don't need to inject a db_conn.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you encapsulate the following code in another method that you can call from either the if or the else block:

```
insert(
            table=schemas.commandchatbot.TABLE,
            document={
                'question': question,
                'answer': answer
            }
        )
```

Comment: Yes, like I said, I know I can do that. But code like these with different implementations are everywhere. So I have to make new functions on insertion, deletion, and so on, even worse, this is only for commandchatbot class, another class have different implementations. It's silly if I create a function if it is just used inside a single function, or it isn't?